# Location Data, gps tracker, google maps, HTML, js, "режим глобуса"

Tags: javascript, html

Видел множество статей под андроид, где gps работает [отслеживая движение, направление, как на гугл карте](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/location#my-location) в мобильной версии. Собственно, вопрос, а можно ли такое сделать на сайте))) понимаю, со стационарным компьютером далеко не уедешь, и смысла в этом, возможно не очень много, но если вдруг сайт посетят с мобильного устройства, то я бы хотел, чтобы могли посмотреть их маршрут к маркерам, которые я поставил на карте. Так сказать, аналог уже существующего мобильного приложения от гугл, но сделать её на сайте! И второе, все читал про [карту гугл-земля, она есть на карте гугл как "режим глобуса"](https://www.google.com/maps/). Есть ли возможность её реализовать на сайте?

[image: Есть направление и двигается с перемещением гаджета, попробуйте сами, к примеру, выкиньте телефон из окна]